# I send mistake ETC wallet

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

Pls help me
I bought 0.3 ETH in my ETH wallet, but i send ETC wallet to seller.

[image][image]

Tks

Comment: Hi there. You need to contact Bittrex directly, I'm afraid. They might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Richard Horrocks said you need to contact the support of the Exchange where you sent your ether. Since they must own the private key to the ETC account to which you deposited your ether, they also have access to the same account in ETH.